# $\epsilon$–$\delta$ proof that $\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{1}{x} = \frac{1}{x_0}$ for all $x_0\neq 0$; how to identify $\delta$?

Tags: limits

I would like to use the $\epsilon$–$\delta$ definition of the limit of a function to show that
$$\lim_{x\to x_0} \frac{1}{x} = \frac{1}{x_0}$$
But I'm having trouble identifying a $\delta>0$ for arbitrary $\epsilon>0$ and  $x_0\neq 0$ so that
$$ 0<|x-x_0|<\delta \implies |\frac{1}{x} -\frac{1}{x_0}|<\epsilon$$
How can you find a $\delta$ that satisfies this condition?

Comment: $|\frac{1}{x} -\frac{1}{x_0}|\leq \frac {|x-x_0|} {|x_0|(|x_0|-|x-x_0|)}$

Comment: What's the trouble you are having?

Comment: Very similar to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3091644/prove-that-lim-x-to-3-frac1x-frac13-using-epsilon-delta-definit?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Examine the $4$ cases of $|x-x_0|<\delta$ indivdually.

$$x<\delta+x_0,\;\;x_0>0$$

$$x<\delta+x_0,\;\;x_0<0$$

$$x<-\delta+x_0,\;\;x_0>0$$

$$x<-\delta+x_0,\;\;x_0<0$$

Now

$$\left|\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x_0}\right|$$

$$=\left|\frac{x-x_0}{x_0(\delta+x_0)}\right|$$

$$<\left|\frac{x-x_0}{x_0^2}\right|$$

which gives the answer for this case, and you will need to go through each case separately.

Answer (score 0):

Given $\ \varepsilon > 0.$

If $\varepsilon < \frac{1}{\vert x_0 \vert },$ then $\vert \varepsilon x_0 \vert<1,\ $ and so $$ x \in \left( \underbrace{\ \frac{x_0}{1 + \varepsilon x_0}\ }_{a}, \underbrace{\ \frac{x_0}{1- \varepsilon x_0}\ }_{b} \right) \implies \frac{1}{x} \in \left( \frac{1 - \varepsilon x_0}{x_0}, \frac{1+ \varepsilon x_0}{x_0} \right) = \left( \frac{1}{x_0} - \varepsilon, \frac{1}{x_0} + \varepsilon \right). $$

Else, if $\ \varepsilon \geq \frac{1}{\vert x_0 \vert }\ \left( > \frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{\vert x_0 \vert} \right),\ $ then $$ x \in \left( \underbrace{\ \frac{1}{ \frac{1}{x_0} + \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{\vert x_0 \vert}\  } }_{c}, \underbrace{\ \frac{1}{ \frac{1}{x_0} - \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{\vert x_0 \vert} }\ }_{d} \right) \implies \frac{1}{x} \in \left( \frac{1}{x_0} - \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{\vert x_0 \vert}, \frac{1}{x_0} - \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{\vert x_0 \vert} \right)$$

$$\subset \left( \frac{1}{x_0} - \varepsilon, \frac{1}{x_0} + \varepsilon \right). $$

So let $$\delta:= 
\begin{cases}
 \frac{b-a}{2}&\text{if}\, \varepsilon < \frac{1}{\vert x_0 \vert }\\
 \frac{d-c}{2}&\text{if}\, \varepsilon \geq \frac{1}{\vert x_0 \vert }\\
\end{cases}
$$